# .NET 6 Calling SOAP Service - Realm error in Basic Authentication

Tags: wcf, .net-core, soap, realm, basic-authentication

I am trying to consume a SOAP Service with a .NET 6 client. The service uses Basic Authentication. I am getting error:

*The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="Custom realm"'.*

My code is - to create the binding:

```
    private HttpBindingBase CreateHttpsBinding()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;
        binding.TransferMode = System.ServiceModel.TransferMode.Buffered;
        binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        binding.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

        return binding;
    }
```

And creating the client:

```
            var binding = CreateHttpsBinding();
            using (var wsClient = new ExternalService(binding, new EndpointAddress(url)))
            {
                wsClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = param.Username;
                wsClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = param.Password;

                await wsClient.OpenAsync();

                var response= await wsClient.SomeCall(input);
```

The error is given as an Exception on wsClient.SomeCall();

Comment: Can you update the question as to what it has to do with MongoDB Realm, the relational database per the Tag? I don't see a correlation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the error was given because of incorrect username/password details!

Initially it was worrying as in .NET Core there is no way to set Realm in Binding Security configuration. But this didn't seem to be a problem.